# Doubling metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

A metric space $(X,d)$ is said to be **doubling** if there exists a constant integer $N\ge 1$ such that every closed ball of radius $R$ can be covered by at most $N$ closed balls of radius $R/2$.

**Proposition.**

> If a metric space $(X,d)$ is doubling, then there exist constants
> $C\ge 1, s>0$ such that for every $x\in X$, $0<r<R$ it holds the following implication: if $Y$ is a subset
> of the ball $\mathbb{B}(x,R)$ such that $d(y,y')>r$ for every $y,y'\in Y, y\ne y'$,
> then $Y$ has cardinality less or equal than $C(R/r)^s$.

My questions are the following ones.

1. How can I prove the Proposition? My idea is to use the following remark: every doubling metric space with doubling constant $N$ has de Groot dimension $N$, that is to say, for each $x\in X, r>0$, it holds that the cardinality of $Y$ is less or equal than $N$ for every set $Y\subseteq\mathbb{B}(x,r)$ such that $d(y,y')>r$ for every $y,y'\in Y$ with $y\ne y'$.
2. How can I prove that if there exists a doubling Borel outer measure over $(X,d)$, then the metric space is doubling?

I know that there exists a similar question to the current on MathStack but I'm looking for a more complete and detailed question. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: In your proposition, you refer to "the set of all points of the ball $B(x,R)$ such that their mutual distance is $>r$..."  This is not a parse-able definition.  Perhaps you meant "Every subset of points of the ball $B(x,R)$ such that their mutual distance is $>r$ has cardinality less or equal to $C(R/r)^s$"?

Comment: @MW Yes, exactly. Thank you. I edited my question.

Comment: Hrm... I really don't like this notion of "de Groot dimension"... it doesn't feel very... dimension-y.  Two concepts you might want to look into are "Ahlfors regularity" and "Assouad dimension".  Robinson has a short text which might be relevant... let me see if I can find a reference.

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/dimensions-embeddings-and-attractors/3C621DA218BE433CEC5B0E9C558286F8

Comment: Your proposition is often called the "packing property" or "packing lemma" of metric spaces of bounded doubling dimension. Proofs appear in several places. See, e.g., Lemma 2 of https://people.scs.carleton.ca/~michiel/weakgap.pdf (though it is formulated slightly differently there). A closer formulation can be found in Lemma 2 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.15234.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove the proposition as follows, with $C=N^2$ and $s=\log_2 N$. To prove this, we argue by induction on $[\log_2(R/r)]$, the integer portion of $\log_2(R/r)$.

First some terminology, I will call a set $A$ "$r$-separated" if every pair of distinct points in $A$ has distance greater than $r$.

In our base case, we have $r<R<2r$.  Let $A$ be an $r$-separated subset of $B(x_0,R)$.  By the doubling property, there are balls $B(x_1,r)$, ..., $B(x_N,r)$ covering $B(x_0,2r)\supseteq B(x_0,R)$.  By your de Groot dimension remark, $A$ intersects each of these balls at most $N$ times, and so $A$ has cardinality at most $N^2=C\leq C(R/r)^s$, and the base case is proved.

Now suppose we have established the theorem whenever $[\log_2(R/r)]<k$, and we consider the case $[\log_2(R/r)]=k$, i.e. $2^{k}r\leq R <2^{k+1}r$.  Again $A$ is an $r$-separated subset of $B(x_0,R)$, and we choose balls $B(x_1,R/2)$, ..., $B(x_N,R/2)$ covering $B(x_0,R)$.  Now by the inductive assumption, $A$ intersects each of these balls at most $C(R/(2r))^s$ times, and so $A$ has cardinality at most
$$N C (R/(2r))^s = C N (1/2)^s (R/r)^s= C (R/r)^s\text{.}$$

[Edit: forgot about your second question.]

If you have a doubling measure on the space, then take a maximal $r/2$-separated set $A\subseteq B(x,r)$.  Observe that the balls $B(a,r/4)$ centered around the points in $A$ are disjoint, and must (by a few repeated applications of doubling property of the measure $\mu$) have measure at least $\mu(B(x,2r))/C$ for some constant $C$.

(To elaborate on this, just note that if $C_d$ is the doubling constant of the measure $\mu$, then
$$\mu(B(a,r/4))\geq \mu(B(a,2r))/C_d^3 \geq \mu(B(x,r))/C_d^3 \geq \mu(B(x,2r))/C_d^4\text{,}$$
so we may take $C=C_d^4$.)

Then there can be at most $C$ points in $A$.  On the other hand, the balls $B(a,r/2)$ clearly cover $B(x,r)$, otherwise $A$ would not be maximal.

Comment: @M W I studied your question and now everything is clear, thank you very much, you helped me a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!